# Python assign into variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary and want to assign to variables (named after keys in dict) values (corresponding values in dict). Like this:

```
dictionary = {'n': 5, 'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
assign(dictionary)
print(n)
print(a)

>> 5
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Have tried:

```
for key in dictionary:
    eval(f"{key} = {dictionary[key]}")
```

But found eval does not support variable assignment.
Do you know how?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? How does it help you to have the variable `n`, when you already have the dictionary entry `dictionary['n']`?

Comment: `globals().update(dictionary)` would work, although I don't think you should do this...

Comment: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html

Comment: Yes I agree, it's a "stupid idea" but I have come across legitimate use-cases for doing this

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Using it in my libary for reading from .txt files.

Comment: Quote: "Using it in my libary for reading from .txt files." – It's best to include more context in your question so that others can understand why you want to solve your problem in this way. Also if you explain your actual problem then others here may be able to offer a different, and possibly better solution to that actual problem instead of your current solution approach.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern ! Don't try to do this !

Answer (score -1):

Change `eval` to `exec`, since assignment is a statement to be executed, not an expression to be evaluated.

Edit: As comments point out, exec won't change local variables inside a function (since Python 3 made it a function, see https://bugs.python.org/issue4831). So be aware of this behavior and only use exec when necessary.

Comment: [This fails inside a function.](https://ideone.com/P76uiM)

Comment: Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec): "The default locals act as described for function locals() below: **modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted**." Quoting the locals() docs: "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes **may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter**."

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks for making me aware of this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround you could create attributes with same names as the dictionnary keys:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

dictionary = {'n': 5, 'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
attribs = SimpleNamespace(**dictionnary)
print(attribs.n)  # -> 5
print(attribs.a)  # -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Warning : this works only if keys are strings compatible with Python names

Comment: How is this different from simply using `dictionary["n"]`?

Comment: Just because you CANNOT change the globals namespace of a module programmatically.